# Attributes, How can change them on Disk?

Tags: dvd, secure-erase

I have a DVD-RW disk and I got a file on it that I want to take off. However, it is "Read Only" and it wont let me do anything to this file I can't even erase my disk or format the disk. I would like to get rid of this file. Can any one help ?

Comment: Are you sure it is a re-writable disc?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the format of the disc whether individual files can be erased, if not formatted properly you have to erase the entire disc. Also depends on the software used to burn the disc. Another reason I don't use RW discs, DVD-+R are too cheap to mess with RW issues.

> Certain kinds of writeable CD and DVD discs can be erased and written to many times. If you have a CD-RW, DVD-RW, DVD+RW, or DVD-RAM disc and you use the Live File System file format, you can delete one or more files to make more room on the disc.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Erase-a-CD-or-DVD